# Gridview Data Update by textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

When am trying to update Datagridview with a textbox value it shows empty value in textbox
my code is this.wt's wrong in this. bnddata() has dataset assign to gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        bnddata();

    }
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];


        string emailid = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;


        TextBox txtadress = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtadress");

        con.Open();

        string upd = "update empeasty set adress='" + txtadress.Text+ "' where emailid='"+emailid+"'";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(upd,con);


        int i=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (i > 0)
            Response.Write("Data updated");
        else
            Response.Write("Data not updated");

        con.Close();

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        bnddata();
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear - is the data not getting updated, or is the data missing when you re-bind the data source after the update?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger or checked the data in the table to make sure it's actually there?  If txtAddress.Text is empty, I would expect the corresponding spot in the GridView to be blank after rebinding.

Comment: S,GridView be blank after rebinding. How can i solve this. pl explain me.

Comment: Check the following things:  Was the update successful?  What are the values in the table after the update?  What is in the DataSet when the GridView is rebound after the update?  For items 1 and 2, use the debugger and step through the code.  For item 2, look at the data in the actual table (Either through VS or SQL Server Management Studio).  To use the debugger, put a breakpoint in the RowUpdating function and then hit F5.

Comment: It shows error<Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="emailid" HeaderText="EmailID" ReadOnly="true"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="empid" HeaderText="Emp Id"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="empname" HeaderText="Emp Name"/>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Adress">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <%#Eval("adress") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtadress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: What is the error?  All I see in your comment is markup...

Comment: i didm't know where is the problem but data not stored in db showing empry

Comment: if the data is not stored in the database, then either a) your update command isn't updating the table (which would most likely throw an exception), b) you're passing in blank (empty) values in the update command or c) there was no row in the table with the corresponding e-mail address.  Most likely the issue is some variation of c, maybe b.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down based on what we know from your question and comments.

You're trying to update data (the address) in a database, but it's coming back blank on the postback after the data is bound.

I don't see any exception handling in your code, and you haven't indicated any errors, so that tells me the code is executing without any run-time exceptions.  Since the postback appears to complete (based on what we know), that tells me there's an issue with the Update SQL command.

```
string upd = "update empeasty set adress='" + txtadress.Text+ "' where emailid='"+emailid+"'";
```

Unless you've got exception handling at the application level, it's reasonable to assume that the command was executed.  This means either txtAddress.Text was empty, or there were no rows in the table in the database that had a matching emailid.

The quickest way to see what the SQL string actually looks like is to click in the left-hand vertical grey bar to set a breakpoint (a red dot should show up) next to the line where you set the SQL.

Then hit F5 (to start the application in debug mode), enter a value for the address in the text box, then hit submit (or whatever button you have to make the update).  When the program reaches the point where you set the breakpoint, you can then step through the code, and you can examine the values of txtAddress.Text, emailid and upd to see what they are.

If txtAddress.Text or emailid are blank, there's your answer.  If emailid is not blank, then you probably have an incorrect value and you'll need to figure out why.

It may not seem like it, but you have everything you need to determine the root cause of the problem you're seeing.